# Is "Infinity Stones making the name of Thanos" true?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, infinity-stones

I am listening to rumors (or, facts?) these days that Infinity Stones discovered in the MCU are making the name Thanos:

- **T:** Tesseract (Captain America, Avengers)
- **H:** ?
- **A:** Aether (Thor 2)
- **N:** ?
- **O:** Orb (Guardians of the Galaxy)
- **S:** Scepter (Avengers, Avengers 2)

(The next two Infinity Stones would have **H** and **N** words as their names.)

Is any of this true? Is there an official statement or reputed leak? Or, is this the case in comics? Or, this is mere a lucky coincidence?

Comment: Hey cool. It definitely fits so far. Makes me wonder what the last two will be. Necklace? Helmet?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Helmet sounds promising..

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Necklace is also possible. `Rocket: Necklace of Princess of Medusa Perepelata can be sold for billion credits. Groot: I am Groot.`

Comment: What if the H stood for Heimdall? If you ever look at his chest piece there is an orangeish gem in it. I think it could be the soul gem. And the N could be for Necklace (the necklace that Doctor Strange wears) even though i think that one is a longshot. But who knows. we might find out in November.

Comment: I never thought that the aether is the reality gem. I thought it was the soul gem as it attached itself to a host and that is kind of the premise. I think they should save the reality gem for the inevitable "Marvel vs DC" that will never happen.

Comment: A similar, much more recent question: http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/63230/do-the-infinity-gems-spell-out-thanos

Comment: Their containers spell THANOS, not gems themselves. The last two are Necklace (Eye of Agamotto), and either "Heimdall" or "Helmet".

Comment: @Petersaber But the Aether isn't the container for the Aether.

Comment: @JDoe Aether's cotnainer was never named - it is pretty much a container of it's own

Comment: Also see [this](https://68.media.tumblr.com/c39912a540f6a79b6477e4e0bcb43fe1/tumblr_ou0e6sTsa11w5kveeo1_540.jpg).

Comment: @InfinityWar - I found this while searching to see if the theory was true given the newest movie, if you are interested: https://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/avengers-infinity-war-writers-debunk-that-popular-thanos-theory_us_5add1562e4b009869bfa8d87

Comment: In *Infinity War* Tony tells Peter that the bad guys are trying to steal a **N**ecklace from a wizard, and to obtain the Soul Stone you have to throw a loved one from a really **H**igh mountain (or, as per *Endgame*, at least be nearby when they throw themselves off it). So I think we can consider this proven 100% true!

Comment: If you have enough options to choose from, you can make anything fit. imagine "My user ID is 253751 because I have 2 legs have lived in 5 houses, have 3 favourite types of chocolate, ......."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am little bit late to answer, but the pattern has already been broken. In Doctor Strange (2016) movie,

> Time Infinity Stone was introduced

and its name is: *Eye of Agamotto*.. Only if its name was "Necklace of Agamotto"..

**Update:**
The original premise of the question seems flawed, by the way. As @CreationEdge said in the comment:

> The original theory you describe was already about shoehorning the objects into "names" that fit under a THANOS acronym (and really I don't understand why they went with Orb instead of Hammer for Ronan's Hammer, but whatever)

Yeah, Orb and Scepter weren't actually named in-universe.

**Update 2:**
Maybe, pattern hasn't been broken at all. If in-universe name doesn't matter, we can call *Eye of Agamotto* necklace because it was really a part of a necklace.

**Update 3:** 
Here's final take on everything for fans who want to believe in this theory:

- **T:** Tesseract (Captain America, Avengers)
- **H:** Hydra/ Home of Hydra (Avengers: Infinity War)
- **A:** Aether (Thor 2)
- **N:** Necklace (Doctor Strange)
- **O:** Orb (Guardians of the Galaxy)
- **S:** Scepter (Avengers, Avengers 2)

BTW, this isn't official.

Comment: Why would you accept this as the answer given that the examples in your question don't follow the convention? The name of the stone for O isn't "Orb". So "Necklace of Agamatto" is as valid as "Scepter" or "Staff"

Comment: @CreationEdge Everyone is calling it Orb.. See the image in Thaddeus' answer.

Comment: Right, but it doesn't mean it's actually _named_ the Orb, any more than Loki's staff is named "The Scepter". The original theory you describe was already about shoehorning the objects into "names" that fit under a THANOS acronym (and really I don't understand why they went with **O**rb instead of **H**ammer for Ronan's Hammer, but whatever)

Comment: was the powerstone originally in an orb and only placed in a hammer later? plus accepting your own justification does have a whiff of nepotism

Comment: The answer marked accepted here is incomplete as it doesn't explain H part.... So let me do the completion with complete accuracy THANOS is abbreviation of T(Tessaract - Space stone) H (Heart shaped Herb - Soul stone) A(Aether - Reality stone) N(Necklaced eye of Agamotto - Time stone) O(Orb - Power stone) S(Sceptre/Staff - Mind stone).https://prntscr.com/im03vx

Comment: @VickyDev By no means, Heart shaped Herb was an Infinity Stone..

Answer (score 27):

#### I can't imagine this to be true. If they happen to make the remaining gems fit into this strange anagram, it will be a coincidence, nothing more. Worse, if it's true, it is a sign of the laziest Easter Egg ever.

The Infinity Gems had nothing to do with Thanos in their original inception. However, the Marvel Cinematic Universe may decide to create an underlying mythos where Thanos is more integral to their existence.

- The gems became famous because of Thanos' efforts to bring the gems together and harness their powers for his own mad schemes of planetary and then later universal destruction. The most famous of the gems was the **[Soul Gem](http://marvel.wikia.com/Soul_Gem)**, which was held and used by **[Adam Warlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adam_Warlock)**.

[image]

**[The Infinity Gems:](http://www.comicvine.com/infinity-gems/4055-41041/)** The Infinity Gems are six precious stones of cosmic origin that give the possessor mastery over a certain power. Collecting and using all six gems will give the wielder complete control over the universe. Only the Living Tribunal, judge of the Multiverse, is immune to the wishes of the wielder of the Infinity Gems.

[image]

**Apocrypha:** If you are an old school fan of Marvel, you may have noticed the Infinity Gems are differently colored today than they were in the past. Here are the original colors.

[image]

Comment: I think OP mistook the receptacles for the gems. Scepter, Aether, Orb... aren't the gems. They only are receptacle of it. Maybe Marvel is giving away some hints for those who don't the comics very well.

Comment: Also it has been rumored that the Dr Strange's Eye of Agamotto could be the next gem.

Comment: @Boelabaal: kewl, although unfortunately that doesn’t fit the anagram thing, which strikes me as just the sort of thing Joss might have suggested early on.

Comment: “I can't imagine this to be true.” PUNY HUMAN IMAGINATION

Comment: @Boelabaal Notice that the Eye of Agamoto is kept on a **N**ecklace...

Comment: Seems Boelabaal was correct, so this answer could be updated. The Eye of Agamotto is the time gem.

Comment: It could be updated, IF I subscribed to this notion. I do not. I stand by the notion it is just coincidence, at best.

Comment: And the colours are different again in MCU.

Comment: Now you can clinch this since *Infinity War* is out. The Soul Stone wasn't with Heimdall, in Thor's hammer, with Adam Warlock (Him), on a planet that started with an H, guarded by someone whose name began with an H, or anything like that.

Comment: @Adamant but to obtain it, Thanos did have to throw Gamora from a very great **H**eight. Checkmate!

Answer (score 7):

It's likely a coincidence. T, A, O, and S are all in the top 7 most frequent letters to start words in English ([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_frequency#Relative_frequencies_of_the_first_letters_of_a_word_in_the_English_language)).  So, this being a coincidence is plausible.

Note that H is also pretty high up there on the frequency table, so it's conceivable another Infinity Stone will start with an H coincidentally.  N is further down the table at #15, so it's far less likely an Infinity Stone will start with that letter.

Comment: The basic principle is right, but I think you got the last paragraph backwards. "H" is actually not that common as the *first letter* of a word, much less common than "N".  Much of the frequency of "H" comes from the common words "the", "that".

Answer (score 0):

I didn't think anything of this, then I saw the answer about the necklace. The Infinity Stones don't spell out Thanos, but you could argue their containers do.

Tesseract - for the Space Stone
Hell/Hades - for the Soul Stone
Aether - for the Reality Stone
Necklace - for the Time Stone
Orb - for the Power Stone
Scepter - for the Mind Stone

Comment: _"Hell/Hades - for the soul gem"_ I think I'm missing something here why Hell/Hades?

Comment: because the gem is only obtainable thru sacrifice/death. so basically, death itself is holding the gem

Comment: That seems incredibly stretched and doesn't make much sense to me personally.

Comment: well-you can't get the stone without your loved one dying. They can't just teleport it out of voramir. It really seems the point of the soul gem was it needs a soul to grant it's gem

Comment: It does need a soul for a soul but going from sacrificing a soul to Hell/Hades is a massive leap and is only made to make the acronym fit, it doesn't make much sense. Also using Necklace for the Eye of Agamotto is a leap as well.

Comment: Right-i'm referring to the containers. So orb could also be called a container, the Scepter could be a cane. Hades maybe a stretch, but it could still fit their acronym, and be consistent with the container status.

Comment: Orb and Scepter are the names in universe though, Hell/Hades isn't even mentioned and is a massive leap

Comment: ehh it's arguable either way-but I think it's a clever play on words to fit the whole. I mean hades/death/hell/afterlife/grave/purgatory-Hades(another word for grave) isn't so bad-though hell might be a bit too far.

Comment: I think Nebula actually does describe Vormir as hellish in *Endgame*, when they’re planning the time heist. I’ll look out for that on my next watch.

Answer (score -1):

This maybe true. Adam warlock is referred to as Him while some articles say that the other gem will be in Dr. Strange's world and its receptacle maybe called Necklace of Agamotto.

Comment: This answer looks like it could be good, but doesn't yet contain enough information. Can you please detail what Adam Warlock has to do with the Infinity Stones, when he is refered to as Him and what the Necklace of Agamotto is in your answer, with references if possible?

Comment: I have a feeling that if Dormammu is part of the Dr. Strange movie that he'll be in possession of one of the gems, and somehow Strange will end up with it.

Comment: Close guess... It's *Eye of Agamotto*...